# how to make mkpasswd and python hashlib.pbkdf2 produce the same result (i.e. derived key)

Tags: python, linux, hash, openssl, pbkdf2

I've discovered that mkpasswd and openssl passwd (on the one hand) do not produce the same "derived key" as python hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac() and mbedtls.pbkdf2 (on the other hand), even though both claim to implement the same standard (PBKDF2).

I am trying to compute Linux password hashes on an embedded system.
I use the mbedtls library, which has the function:
`mbedtls_pkcs5_pbkdf2_hmac()`. With the same parameters: SHA256, 5000 rounds, 'TestPasswort' and 'SALTsaltSALTsalt'
I can reproduce the result with pythons hashlib:

```
$ python3
>>> import hashlib
>>> dk = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', b'TestPasswort' , b'SALTsaltSALTsalt', 5000)
>>> dk.hex()
'c27f613f2c4515136f5741a6b80f2fd05c4e3070ab03cb588be842afff6263fe'
```

As a second step, I run the result (32 bytes) through a ***modified*** base64 encoder (see below, for ref).
The final result is:
`kbxVDml33FBjJo4ai.wjo3lCA50f.whMWyV0fzxWMzs`

On the other hand, mkpasswd and openssl produce a different result (but consistent among these):

```
mkpasswd -m sha-256 -R 5000 --salt=SALTsaltSALTsalt TestPasswort
$5$rounds=5000$SALTsaltSALTsalt$NEAgjfoV3kysMtvGP0sS8D0LU9hZlXRnx/g4zn7QPb/

openssl passwd -5  --salt=SALTsaltSALTsalt TestPasswort
$5$SALTsaltSALTsalt$NEAgjfoV3kysMtvGP0sS8D0LU9hZlXRnx/g4zn7QPb/
```

However:

```
kbxVDml33FBjJo4ai.wjo3lCA50f.whMWyV0fzxWMzs
```

and:

```
NEAgjfoV3kysMtvGP0sS8D0LU9hZlXRnx/g4zn7QPb/
```

are clearly different.

Am I making a simple mistake here? How can I make python hashlib.pbkdf2 and openssl passwd produce the same result, or at least map between the two?

------------for ref, my modified base64 encoder:-------------------

```
#!/bin/python3
ascii_lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
ascii_uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
digits = '0123456789'
##note the difference to base64 here:
base64_alphabet = './' + digits + ascii_uppercase + ascii_lowercase     

to_encode = input("base64 encoder ->  ")

chunks_8bit = ''
for bits in to_encode   :
    y = int(bits,16)
    chunks_8bit = chunks_8bit+format(y,'04b')

chunks_6bit = [chunks_8bit[bits:bits+6] for bits in range(0,len(chunks_8bit),6)]
padding_amount = ( 6 - len(chunks_6bit[len(chunks_6bit)-1]) )
chunks_6bit[len(chunks_6bit)-1] += padding_amount * '0'

encoded = ''.join([base64_alphabet[int(bits,2)] for bits in chunks_6bit])
print('Base64 encoded version of {to_encode} is: {result}'.format(to_encode = to_encode,    result = encoded))`
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself:
openssl passwd and mkpasswd do not implement PBKDF2, but:
sha-crypt; see e.g. here:
https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/crypt/sha256-crypt.c.html
and here:
https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt

The basic algo is the same, i.e. repeated application of a hash function as e.g. sha-256. Therefore I was mislead to believe that sha256-crypt would implement PBKDF2 with sha256 as hash function.